# Why Ctrl+Shift works but Shift+Ctrl doesn't?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have always assumed that <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is interchangeable with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as a modifier to certain keystroke commands. For no particular reason, I have been in the habit of typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, I find that only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> is working.

While I may have to retrain my fingers, I wonder why this has occurred, and whether there is a simple way of changing back.

Comment: Please give us an example of a command where the order makes a difference.

Comment: I am going to agree with @sudodus here as I have a clean install of 22.04 in a VM and I cannot duplicate an issue where it makes a difference if you press it as Ctrl+Shift or Shift+Ctrl.  Even in multiple desktops of Xfce and GNOME with Wayland and without Wayland I cannot duplicate where it made any difference.

Comment: For example in typing this comment, to move back one word and highlight it, Shift-Ctrl-Left does not work, but Shift-Ctrl-Left does. I have just reinstalled 22-04 and the problem persists.

Comment: @Pansmanser, It works for me in my installed Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS. I keep the keys pressed all the time and the order that shift and ctrl are pressed does not make any difference. Are you using some special feature, for example that you need not press the keys at the same time, but press them one after the other (I don't know the English term for it)? Or could it be a bug introduced by dist-upgrading from an earlier version? (My 22.04 is a fresh installation.)

Answer (score 6):

I have discovered that the issue arises when I set the *Pointer Location* flag in Tweaks. The *Pointer Location* shortcut key is <kbd>Control</kbd>.

Presumably the system "steals" the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when it is pressed after <kbd>Shift</kbd>. It seems surprising that it happens that way round (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> but not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>), but it is what it is.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how it works :-)

Comment: It's exactly that, but it has to be fixed since it's changing the whole behavior of the keyboard